⨯ GaxiosError: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key
I am using oauth 2, so I dont need api key. But to try it out I did give the api and got the same result. I am using nextjs-auth. I am not sure what else to do . I'd appreciate some help thank you
app
├── api
│   ├── auth
│   │   └── [...nextauth]
│   │       └── route.js
│   └── calendar
│       └── route.js
├── components
│   ├── Appbar.jsx
│   ├── Providers.jsx
│   └── SigninButton.jsx
├── favicon.ico
├── globals.css
├── layout.js
├── page.js
└── page.module.css

//app/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, account }) => {
      if (account?.access_token) {
        token.access_token = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      session.accessToken = token.access_token;
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
// app/api/calendar/route.js
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function GET(req) {
  const accessToken = req.headers.get('authorization')?.split(' ')[1];
  if (!accessToken) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Access Token is required' }), {
      status: 401,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }
  console.log(accessToken);
  console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: accessToken, key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY});
  const res = await calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  });
  console.log("Printing the next 10 events");
  console.log(res);
  return new Response(JSON.stringify("hi"), {
    status: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });

// app/page.jsx
"use client";
import { useSession, signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      fetch('/api/calendar', {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(events => {
          setEvents(events);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error fetching events:", error);
          setEvents([]);
        });
    }
  }, [status]);

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You are not signed in. Please sign in to see your calendar events.</p>
        <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign In</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {events ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Today's Calendar Events </h2>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(events, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading events...</p>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}

I am using the new app router Nextjs. I am getting the following error
⨯ GaxiosError: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.
    at Gaxios._request (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:144:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/calendar/route.js:27:17)
    at async /Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
    at async eU.execute (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964)
    at async eU.handle (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)
    at async doRender (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1317:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1539:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1447:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1844:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1882:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:895:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:269:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:791:17)
    at async /Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/Users/siva/Desktop/tidy-task/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2024-04-11T05%3A30%3A54.916Z&maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&key=ya29.a0Ad52N3-3Ds39qLTF-A1Qg0dQVXcPMup33wgI6nQGyMi-WjLnqfLcA8ohsKhaN_J2tRUU9AVLGu6O3nYUz0cJDG6LRTW0pQL91vbcmW29tmIJDzNPndzsxdm1K_ocwHpnXzXbY33C--aWMyTFQAPKDWx4LDw1t3Zf2Y8LaCgYKAfQSARMSFQHGX2MimtdOsATSNh2aG6LrPz2S8w0171',
    method: 'GET',
    userAgentDirectives: [ [Object] ],
    paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
    headers: {
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/7.1.0 gl-node/20.5.1',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/7.1.0 (gzip)'
    },
    params: {
      timeMin: '2024-04-11T05:30:54.916Z',
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
      key: 'ya29.a0Ad52N3-3Ds39qLTF-A1Qg0dQVXcPMup33wgI6nQGyMi-WjLnqfLcA8ohsKhaN_J2tRUU9AVLGu6O3nYUz0cJDG6LRTW0pQL91vbcmW29tmIJDzNPndzsxdm1K_ocwHpnXzXbY33C--aWMyTFQAPKDWx4LDw1t3Zf2Y8LaCgYKAfQSARMSFQHGX2MimtdOsATSNh2aG6LrPz2S8w0171'
    },
    validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
    retry: true,
    responseType: 'unknown',
    errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor],
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    config: {
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2024-04-11T05%3A30%3A54.916Z&maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&key=ya29.a0Ad52N3-3Ds39qLTF-A1Qg0dQVXcPMup33wgI6nQGyMi-WjLnqfLcA8ohsKhaN_J2tRUU9AVLGu6O3nYUz0cJDG6LRTW0pQL91vbcmW29tmIJDzNPndzsxdm1K_ocwHpnXzXbY33C--aWMyTFQAPKDWx4LDw1t3Zf2Y8LaCgYKAfQSARMSFQHGX2MimtdOsATSNh2aG6LrPz2S8w0171',
      method: 'GET',
      userAgentDirectives: [Array],
      paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
      headers: [Object],
      params: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
      retry: true,
      responseType: 'unknown',
      errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000',
      'cache-control': 'private',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Thu, 11 Apr 2024 05:30:55 GMT',
      server: 'ESF',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    request: {
      responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2024-04-11T05%3A30%3A54.916Z&maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&key=ya29.a0Ad52N3-3Ds39qLTF-A1Qg0dQVXcPMup33wgI6nQGyMi-WjLnqfLcA8ohsKhaN_J2tRUU9AVLGu6O3nYUz0cJDG6LRTW0pQL91vbcmW29tmIJDzNPndzsxdm1K_ocwHpnXzXbY33C--aWMyTFQAPKDWx4LDw1t3Zf2Y8LaCgYKAfQSARMSFQHGX2MimtdOsATSNh2aG6LrPz2S8w0171'
    }
  },
  error: undefined,
  status: 400,
  code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ],
  [Symbol(gaxios-gaxios-error)]: '6.4.0'
}

I tried to use the api key and got the same results. My understanding is if you are using oauth 2, you dont need api key.

try adding x-api-key or google-x-api-key as a header js requires an api key for some reason not sure why
